# I am not able connect with server using WebsocketStompKit in ios 9.2

Tags: ios, websocket

Can any one help me to connect with server using `WebSocketStompKit`. I am getting error:-

> socket did disconnect, error: Error Domain=JFRWebSocket Code=1
>   "(null)" UserInfo={HTTPResponseStatusCode=200, Invalid HTTP
>   upgrade=NSLocalizedDescription}